# What does small signal analysis mean?

Tags: transistors

My syllabus shows that I have to study about transistor amplifiers - including small signal analysis.

What exactly does small signal analysis mean? I googled it but I couldn't find an exact answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Strictly speaking, transistors are very non-linear devices. Bipolar transistors don't amplify at all until the base/emitter voltage rises high enough for the base/emitter junction to be forward biased, and you don't get significant current through a MOSFET until the gate/source voltage approaches the threshold voltage.

However, we can use clever circuits to *bias* the transistors, which means that fairly large d.c. voltages and currents are applied. The bias conditions hold the transistor at an operating *bias point* such that the behavior of the transistor is fairly linear over a small range of voltages or currents surrounding the bias point. Large-signal analysis pertains to setting up the bias conditions and deals with the non-linear behavior of the transistor. Small-signal analysis assumes that the transistor is correctly biased and concentrates on the linear behavior for small signals, ignoring the messy non-linear stuff.

Answer (score 15):

Small-signal analysis consists of:

(1) Finding the [quiescent](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28858/what-is-the-formal-definition-of-quiescent-point) or [operating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biasing) of a circuit.  This is found by zeroing all signal sources leaving just the DC sources and then solving for the DC voltages and currents in the circuit.

(2) Linearizing the non-linear circuit elements at the operating point.  For example, a diode is replaced with a resistor that models the dynamic resistance at the particular operating point.  The dynamic, or small-signal resistance is the ratio of the *change* in voltage to a small (actually infinitesimal) change in current from the operating point.

(3) Finding the small-signal solution. The DC sources are zeroed, the signal sources are activated, and linear circuit analysis is used to solve for the small-signal voltages and currents.

Having solved for the small-signal voltages and currents, the *total* solution is simply the sum of the DC solution and the small-signal solution.  This total solution is an approximation that is valid only when the signals are in some sense *small*, i.e., that the variations of the voltages and currents in the circuit are small relative to the DC voltages and currents.

Answer (score -2):

small signal analysis is carried out on non-linear elements,where non-linear elements are replaced by linear elements(R,L,C) around the operating point of the non-linear device,where the linear equations can be used.